# Statsd gauge value stay the same even if I push every seconds

Tags: node.js, graphite, statsd

I'm using the node-statsd npm package to push statsd notifications from my main node.js application.

1) My main problem is that sometime, the gauge value will stay the same during X minutes (e.g. screenshot)

[image: Gauge value stay the same even if I push every seconds]

I know that the if I don't call the .gauge, the previous value will remain in the chart, but I have a setInterval that push my qps value every seconds, and this is never the same.

2) My second issue is that when I use SET instead of GAUGE, the qps value looks weird (like from 0 to 30), even if I set a number like 100, 200 ...

1) Is that a statsd, a network or a gauge issue ?

2) I really don't know why ...